# Joomla Ajax in Module from Administrator not work

Tags: module, ajax, com-ajax

I have a module that creates thumbnails from the main image and over time the hosting fills with images, for that reason I want to add a maintenance button that deletes the previous images. It is from the administrator, not from the front-end. I have implemented ajax, but for some reason it doesn't work for me and it sends me the following message in broswer console:

```
Object { success: false, message: "The file at mod_my_module/helper.php does not exist.", messages: null, data: null }
```

I need your help, I leave the code used in module.

**helper.php**

```
use Joomla\String\StringHelper;

$com_path = JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/';

JLoader::register('ContentHelperRoute', $com_path . 'helpers/route.php');
JModelLegacy::addIncludePath($com_path . 'models', 'ContentModel');

abstract class ModMyModuleHelper
{
    public  function deleteImagesAjax() {
        $minified_path = JPATH_ROOT . '/cache/mod_my_module_images';
        if(JFolder::exists($minified_path)) {
            JFolder::delete($minified_path);
        }
        die();
    }
}
```

**cleanimages.php**
This file is a custom field type for create button to delete images from module settings

```
jimport('joomla.form.formfield');

class JFormFieldCleanimages extends JFormField {

    protected $type = 'Cleanimages';

    protected function getInput() {

        Jhtml::_('jquery.framework');
        $doc = JFactory::getDocument();
        $doc->addScriptDeclaration('jQuery(function($) {
            $("#btn-reset-css").on("click", function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                var $this = $(this);
                $this.text($this.data("loading"));
                $.ajax({
                    url: "index.php?option=com_ajax&module=my_module&method=deleteImages&format=json",
                    type   : "POST",
                    success: function (data) {
                        $this.text($this.data("text"));
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
                
            });
        });');

        return '<button id="btn-reset-css" class="btn btn-info" data-text="'. JText::_('Cleaned Images') .'" data-loading="'. JText::_('Cleaning Images') .'">'. JText::_('Clean Images') .'</button>';
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**
Doing my own research and reviewing the component I have discovered that com_ajax looks for the helper.php file using `JPATH_BASE` so when executing the button in the administrator it would be looking for helper.php inside the `/administrator/modules/mod_my_module/helper.php` folder , If `JPATH_BASE` were changed to `JPATH_ROOT`, this would work in both admin and front-end but it is core and we cannot change it.
Given this, **is there any way to do it without having to create a module for the administrator?**

**UPDATE 2**
I have solved the problem by calling the full url from the front-end, the code below in the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your AJAX URL is relative and ends up pointing to `administrator/index.php`. You can change that by prepending root path. First, load the required dependencies:

```
JHtml::_('behavior.core');
```

Then change the URL:

```
url: Joomla.getOptions("system.paths").root + "/index.php?option=com_ajax&module=my_module&method=deleteImages&format=json",
```

Comment: Thank you, I will mark your answer as the correct one, but I will also leave the solution that I found to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to those who cooperated on this issue.

I had solved this by calling the public url (full url) of the module from the administrator, without letting `JPATH_BASE` fill in the location. For which modify the url to call by:

```
url: "'.Uri::root().'index.php?option=com_ajax&module=my_module&method=deleteImages&format=json",
```

You must add this  above `use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;`

Maybe it will be helpful to someone else

Answer (score 0):

Am I understanding correctly that your module is on the front end, but you want to call a helper function from the back end?

If yes, I wonder if JPATH_ADMINISTRATOR might do the trick for you?

https://docs.joomla.org/Constants